# customizing typing.NamedTuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm using `NamedTuple`s to hold data, and I want to add a method that can be inherited by multiple `NamedTuple` based classes. But when I try using multiple inheritance or subclassing `NamedTuple` based classes, it doesn't work. Specifically, I'm trying to automatically give all of my data classes a method that can look at the classes annotations and then call some serializing code based on that. Here are some examples of what I've tried:

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Base1:
    def foo(self):
        print(self.__annotations__)


class Test1(NamedTuple, Base1):
    x: int
    y: int


x = Test1(1, 2)
x.foo() # raises AttributeError


class Base2(NamedTuple):
    def foo(self):
        print(self.__annotations__)


class Test2(Base2):
    x: int
    y: int


x = Test2(1, 2) # TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

is there a way for me to use the `NamedTuple` class like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At issue is the metaclass used by `typing.NamedTuple`; this metaclass *ignores* all base classes and just generates a `collections.namedtuple()` class with added annotation information (copying across any additional attributes directly defined on the class).

You can define your own metaclass (which must be a subclass of `typing.NamedTupleMeta`), that adds your additional base classes *after* generating the named tuple class:

```
import typing

NamedTuple = typing.NamedTuple
if hasattr(typing.NamedTuple, '__mro_entries__'):
    # Python 3.9 fixed and broke multiple inheritance in a different way
    # see https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88089
    NamedTuple = typing._NamedTuple

class MultipleInheritanceNamedTupleMeta(typing.NamedTupleMeta):
    def __new__(mcls, typename, bases, ns):
        if NamedTuple in bases:
            base = super().__new__(mcls, '_base_' + typename, bases, ns)
            bases = (base, *(b for b in bases if not isinstance(b, NamedTuple)))
        return super(typing.NamedTupleMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, typename, bases, ns)

class Base1(metaclass=MultipleInheritanceNamedTupleMeta):
    def foo(self):
        print(self.__annotations__)

class Test1(NamedTuple, Base1):
    x: int
    y: int
```

Note that this won't let you inherit fields! That's because you *must* generate a new `namedtuple` class for any combination of fields. The above produces the following structure:

- `Test1`, inherits from

  - `_base_Test1` - the actual `typing.NamedTuple` generated `namedtuple`

    - `tuple`
  - `Base1`

and this works as required:

```
>>> x = Test1(1, 2)
>>> x.foo()
{'x': <class 'int'>, 'y': <class 'int'>}
```

Technically speaking, you’ll only need the above in Python versions up to Python 3.10. Python 3.9 has a refactored `NamedTuple` implementation that fixes the specific metaclass issue underlying this problem, but then introduced a *different* problem by explicitly raising a `TypeError` stating that multiple inheritance is not supported. This `TypeError` was [raised as a bug](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88089), as there are valid use-cases for using multiple inheritance with `NamedTuple`, and the exception was removed in Python 3.11.

You can safely use the code in this answer in Python 3.11, however.

Comment: Have you by any chance try to suggest it to the Python fellows? Because this solution looks much leaner and cleaner, than the other one, where metaclass of the Test1 would be changed, not the mixin

Comment: seems this doesn't work anymore in python 3.10. I get:
TypeError: Multiple inheritance with NamedTuple is not supported

Comment: @Hexxi.m: ah, indeed, `NamedTuple` has been boobytrapped; use `from typing import _NamedTuple as NamedTuple` as a work-around. I’ve updated my answer. This issue was seen as a regression and has been fixed in 3.11