# Python ABC inheritance with collections.namedtuple suppressing implementation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, collections, multiple-inheritance

I'm playing around with Abstract Base Classes and noticed some funky behaviour which I couldn't understand.

Here is an example of behaviour that I would expect - a subclass inheriting from an ABC with an abstract method, but without implementing said abstract method:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyABC(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class MySubClass(MyABC):
    pass

x = MySubClass()  # Raises error for MySubClass not implementing 'foo'
```

However, here is an example resulting in something I don't understand - even though I don't implement the abstract method in the subclass, it doesn't throw an error like in the previous example.  The only thing that's changed is that I'm inheriting a namedtuple as well:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from collections import namedtuple

my_tuple = namedtuple("_some_class", ["arg"])

class MyABC(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class MySubClass(MyABC, my_tuple):
    pass

x = MySubClass("..")  # Doesn't raise an error, even though 'foo' isn't implemented!
```

I also came across some answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860186/namedtuple-class-with-abc-mixin), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530959/generic-namedtuple-in-python-3-6), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941108/how-to-use-namedtuples-in-multiple-inheritance)) that talked about multiple inheritance with named tuples or with ABCMeta classes/mixins, but I couldn't quite piece it together for my particular use-case.  I tried a couple of things, but always ended up with errors such as `Multiple inheritance with NamedTuple is not supported` and `multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict`.

**TLDR;** The aim of this is to get `MySubClass` to throw an error about `foo()` not being implemented, whilst inheriting from an ABC and a `collections.namedtuple`.

Any help for understanding this behaviour would be great :^)

Comment: Also, fwiw, `x.foo()` calls the abstract method.

Comment: The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398966/python-abstractmethod-with-another-baseclass-breaks-abstract-functionality) may be helpful. Seems like it is not specific to `namedtuple`.

Comment: Great, thanks @Mark - that helped a bunch! Take care :^)